# Grub rescue problem all filesystems are unknown

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, windows-7

I know it's pretty common but I can't find which one is the ext file system.

I tried all partitions and all answers were that `Filesystem is unknown.`
and I don't have a CD or flash drive for any OS of them right now.

I work on Windows 7 and I removed Xubuntu without uninstalling, and removing the partitions, so please advise what can I do.

[image]